# Can't set shell variable in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm trying to write a Dockerfile which sets my GOPATH variable however
when I go to use the variable later it is empty such as:

```
Step 7 : RUN export GOPATH=/root/go
---> Running in 5691396dd55b
---> 17d76f7de05f
Removing intermediate container 5691396dd55b
Step 8 : RUN echo $GOPATH
---> Running in b2cd6ef885d0

---> 54b5a3d5c697
```

I tried to doing a docker build -no-cache . but I get the same results;
any ideas?

Comment: Each RUN command is done in a new shell, so internal process state can't be expected to carry through between them. This is just like how running `sh -c 'export GOPATH=/root/go'; sh -c 'echo $GOPATH'` will also not reflect the former change in the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ENV` to set environment variables in a Dockerfile.

Please see https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env

Additional note from the docs:

> Note: Environment persistence can cause unexpected effects. For example, setting `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive` may confuse `apt-get` users on a Debian-based image. To set a value for a single command, use `RUN <key>=<value> <command>`.

The "" part is important because without it, the environment variable is only set for the one layer where the RUN happens, so it has no affect on following layers. `ENV` will persist for child layers.